# Is there an Eloquent way of doing a leftjoin in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, left-join, laravel-5.4

Is there a eloquent way to do a left join in Laravel?

We'd like to get all games and fill in the progress for each one if it exists in user_games.

Right now we've written the following solution, however this isn't eloquent at all, which we like it to be.

public function usergames($user_id) {
return DB::table('games')->leftJoin('user_games', function ($join) use ($user_id) {
$join->on('user_games.game_id', '=', 'games.id')->where('user_games.user_id', '=', $user_id); })->get();
}

DB model: [image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do this without you actually writing a left/inner join is to use the eloquent relationships.

In your case you will have 2 model classes: `User` and `Game`

```
class User extends Model {
    public function games() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Game::class);
    }
}
```

Now, you can access the user's games like so:

```
$user = App\User::find($user_id);
$usergames = $user->games; // Illuminate\Support\Collection
```

If you want to get a list of users with games, then look into eager loading. That would look something like this:

```
User::with('games')->get();
```

This way, Eloquent will know to lazy load the relationship meaning it will only run 2 queries. One to grab the users. and one to grab the games associated with the user, and then make them available for you in the 'games' property of the `user` object.

Comment: If I read your code properly, it would return all the games related to the user. I would like to see all the games which aren't related to user at the same time too, allowing me to say either "continue" or "start game" based on whether there is a User_game record for it or not

Comment: you could check if the game exists in the user's game collection. if it exists, show "continue", if  not show "start". why do you want to get all the games? what if they end up to be millions of games?